# Android : Activity already started.. do I have to queue it if I want naother instance

Tags: android

I have activity which is used for survey questionnaire.

So based on some events I have to trigger this survey activity from background service.

Suppose if the application is already running and if survey is triggered again, Android won't invoke the activity again since its already running.

But for the above usecase, I want the user to take the survey twice. So do I have to maintain some queuing mechanism in service and chk if the survey application is not already running then wait for it to end and then start activity. IS there any in built mechanism available in android??

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, having a background service start an activity could be really annoying to an end user if they are in the middle of something.  I would suggest you have the service fire a Notification via the NotificationManager and use a PendingIntent to run the survey UI once the user views the notification.

Seems there are a number of ways to handle the situation where a second "survey trigger" occurs while the survey activity is already active.  One simple approach is to always have your service persist the triggers using either a SQLite database or the file system.  Whenever the survey activity finishes an activity you go back to your data store and see if any other survey triggers occurred since the survey activity started.

Hence when a trigger event happens your service will always:

```
persist the survey event to db/filesystem
fire a Notification if survey activity is not already running.
```

And your survey activity will essentially present a UI that does this:

```
while there are more survey events stored
    present survey to user
    remove survey event from db/filesystem
```